# sorting according to the sequence number

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

```
A_xyz_01
B_mdd_01
A_djk_02
A_jfc_03
B_dmk_01
A_bcd_01
B_csd_02
B_dlf_03
A_jhf_02
B_dld_02
```

I want this lines to be sorted like below according to the seq number (the last two digits of each line) max seq is 03 and after 03 i need the  seq 01 for the same switch id(first character in the line A,B):

```
A_xyz_01
A_djk_02
A_jfc_03
A_bcd_01
A_jhf_02
B_dmk_01
B_csd_02
B_dlf_03
B_mdd_01
B_dld_02
```

the above list is actually the output of ls command.
i have files comeing from different switches(A,B,C).they have the sequence number as the third field.for each and every file i need to take the name of the ile do something else.
but this should be done one switch at a time that too i need to do it in sequential order (considering the third field).if the sequence is maximum i need to have the file with 01 as as the sequence but a different file from the earlier 01 sequence file.This step need to be repeated untill all the files of the same switch are over.

Comment: The question is not clear at all. Do you want to sort by the first column as well? Why does `A_bcd_01` follow `A_jfc_03`?

Comment: i wanted to sort initially with the first column and then with the 3 rd column separately for A and B.I donot care about the 2nd column

Comment: That still doesn't explain why `B_mdd_01` comes after `B_dlf_03`.

Comment: Because 3 is the maximum sequence to have for B.and then again it should start with 01 for B

Comment: added some more lines to be more clear.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "sorted" is the wrong word. I'm not sure what the right word is, but figuring that out might be the key to solving the problem.

Comment: downvoter.my requirement is pretty much understandable. then why -1?

Comment: Is "A_xyz_01" before "A_bcd_01" because of it's order in the original list or would it not matter if these two were swapped around?

Comment: Sorry, but your questions is still not clear. Please explain ' why B_mdd_01 comes after B_dlf_03' OR doesn't that case matter? Can we completely ignore the 2nd column? It donest' look like it given that example shows 2 B_*_01 that are seperated from each other. Is the 2nd column deliberately sorted by reverse? Hm.. no because in the A section 2nd column is sorted normally. Do you see our confusion? Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the expected output is approximate (i.e. the second column in the example output could be different):

```
awk -F_ '{ 
  print $0, b[$3, $1]++ 
  }' OFS=_ infile | 
    sort -t_ -k1,1 -k4,4n -k3n |
      cut -d_ -f1-3
```

I didn't tested the script thoroughly though ...